Eliminate empty vertical space only after lstlisting but not lstinputlisting
Given:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  aboveskip=10pt,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  escapechar=@,
  keepspaces=true,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  title=\lstname,
  xleftmargin=.4in
}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

whenever I do something like:
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "hello, world\n" );
}
\end{lstlisting}

I got excessive vertical space after listings, but only for lstlisting listings, not lstinputlisting listings.  From this answer, I can instead do:
\begin{lstlisting}[belowskip=-1.5 \baselineskip]
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "hello, world\n" );
}
\end{lstlisting}

and it looks correct, but I'd rather not have to repeat [belowskip=-1.5 \baselineskip] for every lstlisting. If I move belowskip=-1.5 \baselineskip to be inside lstset, then I get too little space after lstinputlisting.  I also tried setting belowcaptionskip, but that didn't help.
How can I make both lstlisting and lstinputlisting both have the same amount of vertical space after without having to specify [...] anywhere?

Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be best if you could extend your code snippet to a full compilable example that shows the document class and relevant packages and which reproduces the problem you have.

I added more preamble stuff.

Your problem is caused by title=\lstname.
In the following, I use two column output to show the differences: in the left column I removed the option, which is added back in the right column.
You see that the file name is added after \lstinputlisting, but also an empty line is printed below the lstlisting environment.
In the middle you see why setting belowskip is wrong, because it doesn't fix the actual issue.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "hello, world\n" );
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\lstset{
  language=C,
  aboveskip=10pt,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  escapechar=@,
  keepspaces=true,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
%  title=\lstname,
  xleftmargin=.4in
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "hello, world\n" );
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{lstlisting}[belowskip=-1.5 \baselineskip]
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "hello, world\n" );
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\lstinputlisting{\jobname.c}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\newpage % side by side column

\lstset{title=\lstname}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "hello, world\n" );
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{lstlisting}[belowskip=-1.5 \baselineskip]
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "hello, world\n" );
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\lstinputlisting{\jobname.c}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}


How can you specify title=\lstname only for \lstinputlisting? Modify \lstinputlisting to set locally the option.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "hello, world\n" );
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\NewCommandCopy{\originallstinputlisting}{\lstinputlisting}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\lstinputlisting}{O{}m}{%
  \originallstinputlisting[title=\lstname,#1]{#2}%
}

\lstset{
  language=C,
  aboveskip=10pt,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  escapechar=@,
  keepspaces=true,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  xleftmargin=.4in
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "hello, world\n" );
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\lstinputlisting{\jobname.c}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}



Actually, I just deleted title since I'm using caption for lstinputlisting anyway. Now both listing types are consistent. I still needed to add a belowskip=2pt to lstset to make the make the space before/after to look the same. It's not clear why it's not 10pt to match the aboveskip.

@PaulJ.Lucas parskip

Can you be more specific? If leave out the belowskip, it spaces just a tiny bit too much. Given the font is 10pt, I'd expect a value like 8pt to reduce it by a tiny bit, but I don't get why a value of 2pt works.

@PaulJ.Lucas You use a nonzero \parskip. Don't, and your life and documents will be better.

But then wouldn't there be no space between paragraphs? I want a blank line between.

@PaulJ.Lucas And the answer is with a question: why? Take a few books off your shelf and check how many of them use that style.
